# How do I make a pageblock title inside of a panelgrid span the full width of the pageblock?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I have multiple `<apex:pageblock>`s in an `<apex:panelgrid>`. The title of the `<apex:pageblock>`s wraps prematurely, and I can't figure out why. Here's an example of what it looks like.

[image: pageblock_title_wrapping_exapmle]

I don't seen any reason why the title shouldn't span the entire width of the `<apex:pageblock>`. Anyone else? I'm also open to hacks to get around the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce wraps the title in a `<td>` and sets its width to 30%. You can override this with some css like

```
td.pbTitle {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. This did the job.

.bPageBlock .pbTitle {
    width: 80%;
}

Comment: I see why the standard style is like the way that it is now. The pageblockbuttons are in the next <td>, and if you set the width of .pbtitles for all pageblocks (including those with buttons), the ones with buttons will push the buttons too far to the right.

Comment: You can use CSS selectors to target specific pageblocks. In my example, it'd be `#j_id0\:j_id1\:myPageBlock td.pbTitle`

Comment: I'm wrapping pageblocks without pagebuttons with an `<apex:outputpanel styleClass="noButtonPageBlock">` where `noButtonPageBlock` styles `<td>`s as `width: 80%`. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ditch the standard `title="title text"` and go with the same font/size/bold text with a `min-width` style to protect it from wrapping prematurely.